# electron app keypress console hook alternative for process stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

[electron keyboard shortcuts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts)  , dont go to this link, as this is tutorial for hooking the keypress on the browser, not console.

I understand I can hook key events with this, for the BROWSER WINDOW. How can I do the same for the CONSOLE ?

in nodejs, it goes with `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` YET `process.stdin.setRawMode` is not a property of the app as I run my application with `electron myapp.js` rather than `node myapp.js`

```
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
    
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    process.exit();
  } else {
    console.log(`You pressed the "${str}" key`);
    console.log();
    console.log(key);
    console.log();
  }
});
```

This works well with `node app` but not `electron app` As `isTTY` for node returns `True` but doesn't for electron. I get `process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function`, it is undefined. Any alternatives for electron ? Thank you